# Disable Automerge of Tables in Rational Publishing Engine

Tags: ms-word, ibm-doors, ibm-rational

We are using Rational Publishing Engine to generate documents from IBM Doors.
I want to create a 2x2 table for each requirement in the Doors database, e.g.:

```
ID    SRS-1234
Req   The system shall so some magick
```

However, if I export multiple Doors objects to MS Word, the 2x2 tables are merged into one big table inside the Word document. This means, for example, that a 10x2 table will be generated if 5 subsequent Doors objects are being exported.

Does anybody know a trick to hinder RPE/Word from merging the tables?
I would like to avoid adding additional paragraphs as paddings between the tables. Therefore, a setting to disable this behaviour would be my preferred solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the programming language(s) you're using, but I can tell you what Word needs: A single paragraph mark (ANSI 13) between each table.

Comment: Hi Cindy, an additional paragraph between the tables is my current solution. I just thought there is another, smarter way to achive this. The RPE is btw. no programming language but an add-on tool to IBM doors for document generation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Publishing_Engine).

Comment: You need the paragraph mark - there is no alternative - because *Word* needs the paragraph mark to store information about the table. If you don't want the space to be visible you can format the paragraph mark with a minimal font size (1 pt) and make sure there's no paragraph space before/after, etc.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've written the information up as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to keep two adjacent tables from merging into one is to place a paragraph mark (ANSI 13) between them. Word requires a paragraph mark at the end of a table - it uses that structure to store information about the table, relative to the surrounding text.

If the paragraph mark should be less visible it can be formatted with a small font size (minimum: 1 pt). It might also be necessary to check the paragraph Before/After spacing and possibly the line spacing.

Should you need this a lot in a document it's a good idea to create a `Style` for this set of formatting and apply the style, as needed.